# ActiveRecord::ReadOnlyRecord: ActiveRecord::ReadOnlyRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

Im trying to update attributes massively to my User model,
and I'm doing:

```
u = User.with_any_role(:pro, :admin)
u.each {|user| user.update_attributes(is_pro: true)}
```

But I'm getting this error:

```
ActiveRecord::ReadOnlyRecord: ActiveRecord::ReadOnlyRecord
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/persistence.rb:465:in `create_or_update'
```

WTH?

Comment: Can you edit your question to show the source of `with_any_user_role`?

Answer (score 2):

Your `with_any_role` scope probably specifies a joins condition. Rails flags records loaded with joins as readonly by default. You can override this behavior by calling `readonly(false)` on your scope.

`u = User.with_any_role(:pro, :admin).readonly(false)`

Comment: Im getting this error:

NoMethodError: undefined method `readonly' for #<Array:0x007fee95395680>

Comment: Can you edit your question to show the source of `with_any_user_role`?